# access to Kendo pop up editor input text box

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid which has a pop up editor,when I click on the edit,it pop ups an editor box which I can edit field,in the editor I have text boxes which is created dynamically,how can access them?because my code is correct but no reaction I get ,here are my fields and at the end is my code:

```
 columns: [
                                              { field: 'userName', title: 'userName', width: '100px'},
                                              { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '80px' },

                                              { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" }],
                        editable: "popup",



 $('[name="userName"]').click(function () {

        alert("you can not edit username");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should hook up the `click` function within the `edit` function of the grid itself:

```
edit: function(e) {
    $('[name="userName"]').click(function () {
        alert("you can not edit username");
    });
},
```

Here is a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/inECE/4) to illustrate the above in action.

Comment: it was really a great help,appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide your element to prevent accessing:

```
edit: function(e) {                        
e.container.find("input[name=userName]").parent().hide(); }
```